# laravel event not send to pusher

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

i have pusher app, then i try to send message to pusher by laravel event, this is my event :

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewOrder
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $email;
    public $message;


    public function __construct($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->message = "New order from {$email}, please check.";
        //
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['new-order'];
    }

}
```

and i try to test it with route test,

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    event(new App\Events\NewOrder('John'));
    return "Event has been sent!";
});
```

my pusher configuration have been configured like my pusher's account configuration, but after access `/test` , the pusher debug console doesn't show anything.

[image]
this is my broadcasting.php

```
    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),


    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                // 'cluster' => 'ap1',
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

i don't know to see pusher's log from laravel app, anyone can help me?
i'm using laravel 5.5

Comment: https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/getting-started/server-debugging.html

Comment: i did that code but everytime i run php artisan serve, it's showing ``Pusher class doesn't exist`` @Quezler

Comment: Then either you haven't installed the pusher SDK or you need to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Did you install pusher as mentioned on the laravel broadcast documentation page? `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"`

Comment: yes i did install it

Comment: i'm following tutorial by pusher web in this link : https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-notifications-laravel-pusher-channels

Comment: anything in `./storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: nothing about pusher

Comment: Did you use the event fire?

Comment: what does it mean? i use event() method, as instructed by tutorial

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the problem is with your event class declaration, you should implement `ShouldBroadcastNow` as it fires the event immediately and doesn't require queue implementation. By default you need to set up a queue and then run that queue to fire  events.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
class NewOrder implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
  ....do your stuff....
}
```

And also checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwAKR305CRO9rlj-U9oOi4m2sQaWN6XA8) amazing playlist, this will solve your all problems for sure

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem for about 2 hours.

You forgot to implement broadcast,

you can either use:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
class NewOrder implements ShouldBroadcastNow
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
class NewOrder implements ShouldBroadcast
```

The latter then requires a queue driver

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you! I wish the laravel docs made this more clear

Answer (score 3):

check .env file `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` or you must run `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: this was the solution for me. I had `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` with
`class NewOrder implements ShouldBroadcast`. I just runned `queue:work` and it works. Also, replacing `ShouldBroadcast` with `ShouldBroadcastNow` works for me without running `queue:work`

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
class NewOrder
```

With this:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
class NewOrder implements ShouldBroadcast
```

That should work. Let me know if I can help more.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had this problem too and fix it by clearing the cache! Here is the code!

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan optimize --force
```

Hopefully it can be helpful to you!

Answer (score 1):

Please restart the queue after any change related to pusher.(This is working for me after changing Pusher API keys).

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Here How I Resolve the error

1. Make Sure that the Broadcasting service is enabled in config/app.php
2. Add csrf_token meta tag in the page

```
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
            var key = '<?php echo env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') ?>';
            var pusher = new Pusher(key,{
                cluster: 'ap2',
                forceTLS: true
                });
            var channel = pusher.subscribe('channel-name');
            channel.bind('App\\Events\\EventName',function (data) {
                console.log("OK");
                console.log(data);
            });
```

Comment: I believe you meant config/app.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
'useTLS' => true
```

option solved my issue.

```
'options' => [
     'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
     'useTLS' => true,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as above and none of the solutions fixed my problem.
My problem was related to the `BROADCAST_DRIVER` value from the env file.

Even if the default value from the `broadcasting.php` was set to pusher, my env file was wrong.

```
    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),
```

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
```